# Postgres Enterprise Manager - PEM worker agent continuously restarts

Tags: postgresql-11, enterprisedb

**DB Host:** Centos 7

**DB Host PEM Agent version:** edb-pem-agent v7.12.0-2.rhel7

**DB Host DB Version:** Postgresql v11.2

**PEM HOST:** Centos 7

**PEM Host PEM Server version:** v7.8

**PEM Host DB Version:** EDB Postgresql v11

**Issue:** After PEM Agent updated, the PEM Agent continuously restarts, once per second.

**Background:** Everything was working before PEM Agent updated. A handfuls (5 or 6) pem agents were updated all at the same time. All worked without a problem except for one. After the update, the PEM Agent stoped responding to the PEM Server.

**PEM Agent Log file:**

```
2020-02-28.11:00:40 Worker application restarted.
2020-02-28.11:00:41 Worker application restarted.
2020-02-28.11:00:43 Worker application restarted.
2020-02-28.11:00:44 Worker application restarted.
2020-02-28.11:00:45 Worker application restarted.
2020-02-28.11:00:46 Worker application restarted.
2020-02-28.11:00:47 Worker application restarted.
2020-02-28.11:00:48 Worker application restarted.
2020-02-28.11:00:49 Worker application restarted.
2020-02-28.11:00:50 Worker application restarted.
```

**Actions taken:**

1) Uninstalled and reinstalled
systemctl stop pemagent
yum remove edb-pem-agent
yum install edb-pem-agent
systemctl start pemagent
 systemctl status pemagent

2) On the PEM Server, I removed DB Host entry (agent entry) and re-registered, re-issuing/validating cert and key

3) Validated pg_hba.conf on PEM Server and DB Host (PEM Agent)

4) Validated username and password used in PEM Server for communication.

**My question:** Any advice/tips on where to troubleshoot next? EDB PEM documentation is abysmally absent when it comes to troubleshooting.

Comment: This situation occurs when the pemworker is started but fails for some reason.  The agent will sleep 1 sec and try again until the pemworker starts and runs without failing.  Are there any other errors or messages in the log?  Any hints from the Postgres log?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Postgres log: 
`2020-03-02 15:20:09 MST [18182]: [1-1] user=postgres,db=postgres,app=Postgres Enterprise Manager - Agent Monitoring,client=<IP_Address> LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer`
`2020-03-02 15:20:26 MST [18413]: [1-1] user=[unknown],db=[unknown],app=[unknown],client=<IP_Address> LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer`

I changed the agent.cfg `log_level` to debug2 and it didn't give any further helpful information. Just connection info.

Comment: so that means there was some sort of crash or issue on the pemworker/pemagent side--are there other logs?  Or turn up verbosity on pemagent log?